# cpp pointer for function write on binary file

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers, binaryfiles

I tried to create function that get pointer for the functions of binary file, write and read.
Both of functions need get :

1)char* (on write function the char* mean from witch address write, and on read function char* mean , to witch address read)

2)  int (on write address that meam how many wirte and on read function that mean how many read).

I want create function that get pointer for read/ write , but i get an error
my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <fstream>

void func(void(*funcToCall)(char*, int))
{
    char * temp= "zzz";
    funcToCall(temp, 3);
}
int main()
{
    fstream dskfl;
    dskfl.open("aa.txt", ios::out |  ios::binary);
    dskfl.close();
    dskfl.open("aa.txt", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary);

    char ddd[]= "fffff";
    dskfl.write((char*)ddd, 5);
    dskfl.seekp(0);

    func(dskfl.write);
    dskfl.close();
}
```

i get error on line

```
func(dskfl.write);

Error   1   error C3867: 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::write': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::write' to create a pointer to member
```

why please?

Comment: You need two pieces of information to call a method of a class - instance of the class and the method to call. `fstream* instance = &dskfl;` and `void (fstream::*method)(char*, int) = &fstream::write;` and then use `(instance->*method)(char*, int)` to call the method.

Comment: @Vishal
i changed to
"void func(fstream* instance, void(fstream::*method)(char*, int) )"
and call of function like
 func(&dskfl,&( fstream::write));
i get error


 4 IntelliSense: argument of type "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> &(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>::*)(const char *_Str, std::streamsize _Count)" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (std::basic_fstream<char, std::char_traits<char>>::*)(char *, int)"

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `lambda`

for example:

change the signature of your outer func for receive a `std::function`:

```
void func(std::function<void(char*, int)>&& funcToCall)
```

and call it like this:

```
func([&dskfl](char* c, int i){ dskfl.write(c, i); });
```